# Using arma::mat instead of NumericVector made my code twice as fast. Why?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I was trying to optimize some of the `Rcpp` code in the `mrf2d` package. After some profiling I found the bottleneck was on the following function:

```
NumericVector conditional_probabilities_mrf(const IntegerMatrix &Z,
                                            const IntegerVector position,
                                            const IntegerMatrix R,
                                            const arma::fcube &theta,
                                            const int N, const int M,
                                            const int n_R, const int C){

  NumericVector probs(C+1);
  double this_prob;
  int dx, dy;
  int x = position[0] -1; int y = position[1] -1;

  for(int value = 0; value <= C; value++){
    this_prob = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_R; i++){
      dx = R(i,0); dy = R(i,1);
      if(0 <= x+dx && x+dx < N && 0 <= y+dy && y+dy < M){
        this_prob = this_prob + theta(value, Z(x+dx, y+dy), i);}
      if(0 <= x-dx && x-dx < N && 0 <= y-dy && y-dy < M){
        this_prob = this_prob + theta(Z(x-dx, y-dy), value, i);}
    }
    probs[value] = exp(this_prob);
  }
  return(probs/sum(probs));
}
```

While exploring my options, I was tweaking with types and started using more Armadillo types, and changed to (note that the only difference is the use of `arma::colvec` instead of `NumericVector`):

```
arma::colvec conditional_probabilities_mrf(const IntegerMatrix &Z,
                                            const IntegerVector position,
                                            const IntegerMatrix R,
                                            const arma::fcube &theta,
                                            const int N, const int M,
                                            const int n_R, const int C){

  arma::colvec probs(C+1);
  double this_prob;
  int dx, dy;
  int x = position[0] -1; int y = position[1] -1;

  for(int value = 0; value <= C; value++){
    this_prob = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_R; i++){
      dx = R(i,0); dy = R(i,1);
      if(0 <= x+dx && x+dx < N && 0 <= y+dy && y+dy < M){
        this_prob = this_prob + theta(value, Z(x+dx, y+dy), i);}
      if(0 <= x-dx && x-dx < N && 0 <= y-dy && y-dy < M){
        this_prob = this_prob + theta(Z(x-dx, y-dy), value, i);}
    }
    probs[value] = exp(this_prob);
  }
  return(probs/sum(probs));
}
```

This change alone made my code a lot faster, see the following results from the profiler (before and after, respectively):
[image]

[image]

The same code was used in the two pictures of the profiler data. Note that, the function that appears as a bottleneck in the profiler data is the `log_pl_mrf` that uses the `conditional_probabilities_mrf` function, and is defined as:

```
double log_pl_mrf(const IntegerMatrix Z,
                  const IntegerMatrix R,
                  const arma::fcube theta){

  int N = Z.nrow(); int M = Z.ncol();
  int n_R = R.nrow();
  int C = theta.n_rows - 1;
  double log_pl = 0.0;
  double this_cond_prob = 0.0;
  IntegerVector position(2);
  int zij = -1;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
      zij = Z(i,j);
      position[0] = i+1; position[1] = j+1;
      this_cond_prob = conditional_probabilities_mrf(Z, position, R, theta, N, M, n_R, C)(zij);
      log_pl += log(this_cond_prob);
    }
  }
  return(log_pl);
}
```

Why did the simple change of return type made the performance so much better? How can I understand that? While I'm glad that it did improve, I think understanding why would be important so I could possibly find more performance improvement opportunities in the future.

Comment: What platform are you on? This could just be as simple as having access to (some) OpenMP via (Rcpp)Armadillo but not in plain Rcpp.   You are on the right path here and should be able to drill down via profiling where the action is.

Comment: @AdaLovelace I'm on `aarch64-apple-darwin20`. That seems plausible, although as far as I understand, the OpenMP access would be used for the exponential and sum computations only, but that gave me some ideas on new parameters to experiment with.

Comment: If it is not OpenMP / multithread (which remains difficult for R on macOS for "reasons") then it is more curious.  Would be good to drill down and see if you see it at, say, basic column sum etc.  Armadillo is good though and may well have extra aces up its sleeves.